# "unable to resolve host MongoDB" while trying to launch "sudo service mongod start"

Tags: linux, mongodb, service, ubuntu-16.04, host

I have a machine on DigitalOcean running on Ubuntu 16.04 (I used lsb_release -a)

It is a one-click MongoDB machine, but suddenly it stopped working. Trying to resolve it, I tried many things:

- `service mongod status`
- `rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
  153  service mongod restart`
- looking at logs, there was no change... `less /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`
- There was no result in  `systemctl list-unit-files | grep mongo`
- The mongod service was't even listed in `sudo service --status-all`
- My conf `less /etc/mongod.conf` looked OK, however I noticed there was two database... one at `/var/lib/mongodb` and another one at `/data/db/` like if there had been a migration at some recent point
- `iptables -L` seems fine
- I tried `mongod --repair` but i had still the issue
- I made sure the db was owned by the mongo user `sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb db`

Then I decided to reinstall mongo-org

- `sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*`
- `sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
  sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb`
  ...
- `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`
  But still didn't work

So after 2 hours, I still had the same issue after running `sudo service mongod start`

> unable to resolve host MongoDB

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out. The main issue wasn't related to MongoDB afterall. Because I had created a DigitalOcean oneclick mongo server, the name of the machine was MongoDB. It was confusing for this debug.

I read this at some point and tried out
https://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-user

Turns out that in my hosts I was missing the machine name.

when typing `less /etc/hostname` i read

> MongoDB

So i changed `sudo nano /etc/hosts`
from

> 127.0.1.1 TEST-MONGO TEST-MONGO

to

> 127.0.1.1 TEST-MONGO TEST-MONGO MongoDB

And it solved my problem